# Visualizing hierarchical content/taxonomy in prismic.io admin

Tags: content-management-system, content-model, prismic.io

I am trying to create a taxonomy similar to this:

```
Category 1
  Category 1.1
  Category 1.2
Category 2
  Category 2.1
  Category 2.2
```

etc.

It is possible to create taxonomies based on group selections of hierarchical content, but at the time of the selection, the hierarchy is not visible. Having a complex taxonomy requires exposing this visual hierarchy as it is not possible for the editor to memorize what sub- (and sub-sub-!)categories belong to which parents.

Also, selecting Category 2.2 should automatically select Category 2.

Are these a possibility?